# Testing Ember Data 1.0.0 with JasmineJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, jasmine

In general I'm trying to test my ember models with jasmine.  In [Ember Data 1.0.0 we no longer have](https://github.com/amirdt22/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md) `App.Model.find` or `App.Model.createRecord`.  Instead we have `this.get('store').find` and `this.get('store').createRecord('model', {})`.

### How can I get a handle on the store in my tests?

#### injecting store

I've looked into [injecting it](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_inject) but haven't had luck.

Encompass.inject(this, 'store', 'store');

I think this is because the object I'm injecting into `this` isn't the right type.

#### creating store

I've also tried creating a store locally:

```
describe("A Folder", function() {
  var store = null;
  var folder = null;
  beforeEach(function(){
    Encompass.Store = DS.Store.extend({
      adapter: Encompass.ApplicationAdapter
    });
    store = Encompass.Store.create();
  });
```

but using the store as in

```
store.find('folder');
```

results in `TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookupFactory' of undefined`

I think this is because the container doesn't exist (in time?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your store is trying to access the container but it isn't present. You will need to create manually. And for each model tested you will need to register in the store using:

```
container.register('model:folder', Encompass.Folder);
```

You updated test is the following:

```
describe("A Folder", function() {
  var store = null;
  var folder = null;
  beforeEach(function(){
    Encompass.Store = DS.Store.extend({
      adapter: Encompass.ApplicationAdapter
    });
    var container = new Ember.Container();
    container.register('model:folder', Encompass.Folder);
    store = Encompass.Store.create({
      container: container 
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to get me further, now I get "No model was found for 'folder'" and "Cannot set property 'store' of undefined".  It seems there is no factory?

Comment: I updated the answer. Your store is trying to acess the Folder model, I think that you have a model called Encompass.Folder right? Each model tested need to be registered using container.register('model:modelName', ModelClass).

Comment: Excellent, so because I am manually creating the store I have to do whatever ember normally does.  Could you point me to where that happens (documentation or source code)?  I understand the container isn't documented for public consumption because it would lead to misuse as Ryan pointed out.

Comment: This is the [container code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/container/lib/main.js), the methods have some documentation.

Comment: Helped me a lot, thnx!

Answer (score 2):

If you want your application's store you can just look it up off the container. This is fine to do in your tests, but don't dare do this in production :)

`var store = App.__container__.lookup('store:main');`

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I think the container has not been set up (properly).  I get undefined for App.__container__.lookup('store:main');